# Error message for TYPO3 backend editors

Tags: php, typo3

I want to inform an TYPO3 editor when he clicks on save if a field is unfulfilled or if the entry already exists and interrupt the saving.

Is there already a function in TYPO3 which provides me the posibility to give custom infos and break the saving?

Answer (score 1):

The TCA configures how a backend edit form should behave. For each backend field (often relating to a database column) there is a configuration option `eval` which allows what you want: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#eval

Sadly you can't override that easily for existing extensions via TSconfig (see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/55976).

So you need to change the TCA in PHP code as explained e.g. in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-in-the-overrides-folder

Detailed descriptions would depend on your concrete context.